# Nginx reverse proxy for already deployed mobile api url

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

We have an embedded URL in our mobile project like `https://www.example.com/api/v1`. We can not change this address. We are moving our project to different subdomain so that in nginx we are trying to reverse proxy for reaching out this address.

New address will be `https://api.example.com/api/v1` and when mobile project come to `https://www.example.com/api/v1` nginx will reverse proxy to > `https://api.example.com/api/v1`

any body have an idea? 
Thanks a lot.

```
location ~/api(.*)$ {
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_pass https://api.example.com/api/$1;
}
```

Comment: Is every request made to that exact URL, or do clients access resources with additional URI paths / query strings? Is the API served by the same server / another server on the same LAN?

Comment: We wish to get api json endpoints from another server (domain) same LAN such as when users type https://www.example.com/api/... json comes from https://api.example.com/api/...

Answer (score 2):

This method worked for me.

```
location ~ ^/somepath/?(.*) {
  resolver 192.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  proxy_pass https://api.example.com/$uri$is_args$args;
}
```